# Getting one value from JSON API in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to get one value from JSON. JSON is located in NSString and it looks like this:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-122.38,"lat":37.57},"weather":[{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"Lekka m≈ºawka","icon":"09d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":304.74,"pressure":1017,"humidity":35,"temp_min":300.15,"temp_max":307.59},"visibility":16093,"wind":{"speed":6.7,"deg":250},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1437346641,"sys":{"type":1,"id":478,"message":0.0615,"country":"US","sunrise":1437311022,"sunset":1437362859},"id":5357155,"name":"Hillsborough","cod":200}
```

I'm interested in getting "temp". How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JSON string was stored as a NSString named **JSONString**:

```
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *keys = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                           error:&error];
    NSLog(@"temp = %@", keys[@"main"][@"temp"]); // temp = 304.74
```

---

To get the main sub item in weather, which is an array with multiple items, you should point out its index to tell the selector which object in the array is the one you are looking for. In this case, it's `0`:

```
NSLog(@"weather = %@", keys[@"weather"][0][@"main"]); // weather = Drizzle
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. If I can have one more question: what's about getting "main" from "weather" (in example Drizzle)? I tried to make it similar to temperature, but app crashed. There is extra '[' before.